# Nativescript fails on startup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, vuex, nativescript-vue

Just wanted to test and take a look at Nativescript with Vue but unfortunately it looks like it doesn't work. It instantly crash after having added a couple of rows following a guide, so not the best of the presentation... But maybe I did something wrong /  or the guides are not working anymore as expected and so here I am sharing the initial code I added to see if there is something I can do to let it work properyl:

app.js:

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'
import VueDevtools from 'nativescript-vue-devtools'

import store from './store'
import Home from './components/Home'

if (TNS_ENV !== 'production') {
    Vue.use(VueDevtools)
    Vue.config.devtools = true
    Vue.config.debug = true
    Vue.config.silent = false
}

new Vue({
    store,
    components: {
        Home
    },
    render: h => h('frame', [h(Home)])
}).$start()
```

I added the `VueDevtools` and a Vuex Store:

store/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import users from './modules/users'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    users
  },
  strict: debug
})

Vue.prototype.$store = store;

export default store
```

store/modules/users.js:

```
const namespaced = true
const state = () => getDefaultState()
const mutations = {
  SET_USER: (state, user) => {
    state.user = user
  }
}
const actions = {
  async getUser({ commit }, id) {
    try {
      const user = await this.$axios.$get(`/users/${id}`)
      commit('SET_USER', user)
    } catch (error) {
      throw error.response
    }
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

As you can see everything is very simple. The store I used is a working store from a Nuxt project that I wish to duplicate in Nativescript.

Once I run `tns preview` the output on Mobile is a **Fatal javascript exception** with several Native stack trace (0x101871d50, etc...):

```
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
2020-02-03 10:25:47.484 nsplaydev[14171:3821642] Native stack trace:
1   0x101871d50 NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
2   0x1018b93b0 -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
3   0x102a7e25c -[UIApplication(PlayLiveSync) swizzled_executeModule:]
4   0x101003524
5   0x192909050 <redacted>
2020-02-03 10:25:47.485 nsplaydev[14171:3821642] JavaScript stack trace:
2020-02-03 10:25:47.485 nsplaydev[14171:3821642] handleCopy(file:///app/vendor.js:4255:46)
at file:///app/vendor.js:3942:36
at on(file:///app/vendor.js:3882:23)
at emit(file:///app/vendor.js:3922:29)
at devtoolPlugin(file:///app/vendor.js:29630:19)
at Store(file:///app/vendor.js:29940:18)
at ./store/index.js(file:///app/bundle.js:412:69)
at __webpack_require__(file:///app/runtime.js:751:34)
at fn(file:///app/runtime.js:121:39)
at file:///app/bundle.js:204:83
at ./app.js(file:///app/bundle.js:266:34)
at __webpack_require__(file:///app/runtime.js:751:34)
at checkDeferredModules(file:///app/runtime.js:44:42)
at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///app/runtime.js:31:39)
at anonymous(file:///app/bundle.js:2:61)
at evaluate([native code])
at moduleEvaluation([native code])
at [native code]
at asyncFunctionResume([native code])
at [native code]
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
2020-02-03 10:25:47.485 nsplaydev[14171:3821642] JavaScript error:
file:///app/vendor.js:4255:46: JS ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: HTMLElement
2020-02-03 10:25:47.487 nsplaydev[14171:3821642] PlayLiveSync: Uncaught Exception
2020-02-03 10:25:47.487 nsplaydev[14171:3821642] *** JavaScript call stack:
(

)
2020-02-03 10:25:47.487 nsplaydev[14171:3821642] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: HTMLElement
 at
handleCopy(file:///app/vendor.js:4255:46)
at file:///app/vendor.js:3942:36
at on(file:///app/vendor.js:3882:23)
at emit(file:///app/vendor.js:3922:29)
at devtoolPlugin(file:///app/vendor.js:29630:19)
at Store(file:///app/vendor.js:29940:18)
at ./store/index.js(file:///app/bundle.js:412:69)
at __webpack_require__(file:///app/runtime.js:751:34)
at fn(file:///app/runtime.js:121:39)
at file:///app/bundle.js:204:83
at ./app.js(file:///app/bundle.js:266:34)
at __webpack_require__(file:///app/runtime.js:751:34)
at checkDeferredModules(file:///app/runtime.js:44:42)
at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///app/runtime.js:31:39)
at anonymous(file:///app/bundle.js:2:61)
at evaluate([native code])
at moduleEvaluation([native code])
at [native code]
at asyncFunctionResume([native code])
at [native code]
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
', reason: '(null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x192ecdeb8 0x1920c7f18 0x10187221c 0x1018b93b0 0x102a7e25c 0x101003524 0x192909050)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
2020-02-03 10:25:47.487 nsplaydev[14171:3821642] PlayLiveSync: Uncaught Exception
```

I hope you can help!

Comment: I don't think Vuex Store Or Vue Dev Tools are supported in Preview app.

Comment: Vuex is part of the application. How can you test the app without Vuex?!?

Comment: You can, you will have to build the app locally. Preview is meant for starters and quick testing, not for whole application development.

Comment: Can you add the error output from your terminal window? Often that will show the root cause of the error when it is not shown in the stack trace on the device itself.